# How to get unique value along 1 dim of a 2d array in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a 2d tensor now, which may have repeated elements along a dim, like

```
tmp = torch.tensor([[1,2,3,2,4],[0,5,6,7,2],[3,4,5,3,5],[7,5,6,7,7]])
```

I hope to get unique elements along dim=1, the result should be like this

```
result = [[1,2,3,4],[0,5,6,7,2],[3,4,5],[5,6,7]]
```

Is there a way could get the result without using `for- loop`?

I tried using `torch.unique`,  like this,

```
result=[]
for i in range(tmp.shape[0]):
    t = tmp[i,:]
    result.append(torch.unique(t))
```

It works, but time-consuming.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call unique on n-rank tensor when n>=2.
This is because in PyTorch there are no jagged array tensors.

```
tmp = torch.tensor([[1,2,3,2,4],[0,5,6,7,2],[3,4,5,3,5],[7,5,6,7,7]])
%timeit tmpt =torch.unbind(tmp); [torch.unique(t) for t in tmpt]
```

This returned 39.3 µs, while your original loop took

```
tmp = torch.tensor([[1,2,3,2,4],[0,5,6,7,2],[3,4,5,3,5],[7,5,6,7,7]])
result=[]
%timeit for i in range(tmp.shape[0]):    t = tmp[i,:] ;    result.append(torch.unique(t))
```

54 µs on average